# How is the fraction of a particular neutrino species calculated?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, neutrinos

Suppose we assume that a neutrino is formed in the $\left| \nu_2 \right>$ eigenstate. Then,

\begin{align}
\left| \psi(x, t) \right> 
&= \left| \nu_2 \right> e^{-i\phi_2} \\
&= \left( U_{e_2}^* \left| \nu_e \right> + U_{\mu_2}^* \left| \nu_\mu \right> + U_{\tau_2}^* \left| \nu_\tau \right>\right) e^{-i\phi_2} \\
& \quad \left( c_e \left| \nu_e \right> + c_\mu \left| \nu_\mu \right> + c_\tau \left| \nu_\tau \right>\right) e^{-i\phi_2}
\end{align}

Then, it's straightforward to write
\begin{align}
P(\nu_e \to \nu_\mu ) 
&= \left| \left< \nu_\mu | \psi(x, t) \right> \right|^2 \\
&= \left| c_\mu \right|^2 \\
&= \left| U_{\mu_2}^* \right|^2
\end{align}

But this probability depends neither on the neutrino energy nor on the length it has traveled.

When the starting neutrino is formed in a flavor eigenstate then there are cross-terms and so there is a phase dependence which leads to a dependence on energy and distance but that's lacking here and it does not seem right. What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to do this calculation?

Comment: I'm not sure which step assumed all 3 propagation phases are the same. The phase is $\phi_2$ because the neutrino was formed in the nu_2 eigenstate?

Comment: MathJax supports the `\begin{align} \end{align}` construct for multi-line typesetting. I've gone ahead and applied it here. Note, however, that it treats `align` and as if it were `align*`. If you want equation numbers you have to make them explicit with `\tag{}`.

Comment: Yes, if you have an isolated mass eigenstate, hard to produce, but possible if it is coming from really enormous distances, there *is no* oscillation. When it hits a detector it will resolve into an incoherent sum of "lepton flavor eigenstates" (a term concocted to confuse). In neutrino oscillation experiments you produce all 3 mass eigenstates, as a rule.

Comment: So does oscillation occur only when we're in flavor eigenstates?

Suppose the neutrino above started out as an electron neutrino (instead of nu_2). Would then what I did be a correct way to calculate the fraction that arrives on earth?

Comment: Yes, it is the flavor eigenstates that oscillate. The mass eigenstates are real particles zipping along unolested. What your did is sensible for an initial electron neutrino  *Provided* you have more than one mass eigenstates; the *different* propagation phases will interfere and [produce oscillations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_oscillation#Propagation_and_interference).

Comment: In fact, basically $\nu_2$ s are leaving our sun because of the MSW resonant inversion effect, and do *not* oscillate from there to here. The serious mutation occurred inside the sun.